# How to connect SharePoint Online with Dynamics CRM Online using BDC?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, bdc-model, office-web-apps, dynamics-crm

I try to connect SharePoint Online with Dynamics CRM Online using BDC. But without any results.

I'll try to use Account's from CRM in SharePoint Online like a list.
I mean - when I have 100 account's (customers) in CRM I want to export this accounts to SharePoint Online like a list. And when I will bed edited an account in CRM the elements in the list will be updated (and when I edited element on SharePoint list it will update in CRM).
Is there any possibility to connect in this way? If what I should use - SharePoint Designer 2010, Visual Studio or do this on web interface?